# Difference in CSS media query syntax

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

When I learned to write CSS3 media queries the syntax that was shown to me is this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: Xpx){}
```

Xpx meaning any number you enter of course. As of late, I have seen several other devs, here on Stack mostly, writing CSS media queries simply like this:

```
@media (max-width: Xpx){}
```

When I go to websites like Mozilla's Documentation pages and W3Schools.com, they seem to use it the same way I am, like in my first example. Something else I learned a long time ago is not to write code if I don't know why I am writing it. After seeing that the syntax of the query could be written without the 'screen only' part, I have to ask, what is the difference in how I am writing my CSS media queries, and how other developers are writing theirs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`only screen` means just that: only for screens (as opposed to being for all kinds of media, such as `print` outs).